# Jooq batch insert/delete returning number of rows affected?

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I am trying to batch insert and batch delete a large list of objects using JOOQ and Postgres, and get the number of rows inserted/deleted. I see there are `insert(Collection<P> objects)` and `delete(Collection<P> objects)` provided in JOOQ, however they don't return anything. From searching online I see there's also `batchStore` that might return the number of inserted rows, which I am going to try. But what about delete?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you meant these methods that don't return anything?

- [`DAO.insert(Collection<P> objects)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DAO.html#insert(java.util.Collection))
- [`DAO.delete(Collection<P> objects)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DAO.html#delete(java.util.Collection))

And by `batchStore` you mean [`DSLContext.batchStore()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batchStore(java.util.Collection)). So, would your answer just be to use [`DSLContext.batchDelete()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batchDelete(java.util.Collection))?